# AngularJS Stopping CSS background slideshow showing all pages with ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing my AngularJS project with ng-route and everything works fine but the problem is I have a CSSC full background slide show which i implemented form this site http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/ which work fine. When I click on other pages the content shows but the slideshow shows up as well moving/transitioning in the background. **I want to stop this from happening. I want the slideshow to only show up on the index.html page only.** Any solutions would be appreciated.

--- HTML code ---

```
<body ng-app="bigBlue"> <!--angular directive-->

    <div main-page-navbar></div> <!--angular navbar directive-->

   <div main-slide-show> </div>   <!--angular side show directive-->

    <div ng-view ></div>


    <!-- Additional Java Script Files -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular Files -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- Module/directives -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/main-content.js"></script>

</body>
```

---

------- navbar directive code --------

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#/">Big Blue</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#/">Home </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#overview">Overview </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#map">Map </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

---

------ slide show directive code --------

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>endangered</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>powerful</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>caring</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>loyal</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>intelligent</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>serene</h3></div></li>
        </ul>
```

---

---- Angular Code ----

`var app = angular.module("bigBlue", ["ngRoute"]);` /* New module called big blue */

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/overview', {
        templateUrl : 'overview.html',
        controller : 'whaleController'
    })
     .when('/map', {
        templateUrl : 'map.html',
        controller : 'MapController',
    })

    .otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });


});
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your slideshow directive into the context of the index instead of the context of the entire application. Something like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        template: '<div main-slide-show></div>'
    })
    .when('/overview', {
        templateUrl : 'overview.html',
        controller : 'whaleController'
    })
     .when('/map', {
        templateUrl : 'map.html',
        controller : 'MapController',
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
});
```

And pull the slideshow directive out of the markup.

Comment: Wow it WORKS! I would never have thought of that. Now I know i can call a directive through ng-route without it being directly fixed in the html mark up