# Angularjs slideshow keep going not change when navigate to other page

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working on a single page app project. I think my problem is being unable to assign my slideshow content to a controller.See the plunker for more detail [Background slideshow](http://embed.plnkr.co/tMaCF4Fxhte7lWsZHJiJ/) . (The problem with this plunker the navigation menu not working but it work well on my machine however that's not the problem I'm looking for an answer.)
At the present I have a list of the slide shows of images inside the html body as shown below.

```
<ul class='cb-slideshow'>
  <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>London show</h3></div></li>
  <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>Paris music show</h3></div></li>
  <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>Belfast</h3></div></li>
  <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>Luanda culture</h3></div></li>
  <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>Rome night</h3></div></li>
  <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>Victorial falls</h3></div></li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    template: "<div main-slide-show></div>"
  })
  .when("/page1", {
    templateUrl : "templates/page1.html",
    controller : "page1Controller"
  })
  .when("/page2", {
    templateUrl : "templates/page2.html",
    controller : "page2Controller"
  })
```

Please note this is just some small part of my code and its all working fine apart from the home page which should stop the slideshow when I clicked on the navbar menu list. Can anyone direct me in the right direction please. Thanks

Someone on this site has asked the similar question [background image show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983498/angularjs-stopping-css-background-slideshow-showing-all-pages-with-ng-route) but I still couldn't figure it out for my project.

Comment: it would be great if you can create a Plunker demo replicating the problem.

Comment: @ Manish. Ok here is plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/tMaCF4Fxhte7lWsZHJiJ/

Comment: OK now what you want is that there should be controller associated with with your slideshow. And what about navigation. To me it seems to work fine the only problem i can see is the absence of template files in the plunker. Please elaborate on the problem..

Comment: No missing template, I want when I clicked on page2, the page2 information will be displayed on its page without having the slide show on the background running. The slideshow is only belong/default to the front page only. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference question you have mentioned actually in that the template that has been used is actually a directive. So you need to create a directive for the slide show. And give that directive as a template in your route.

Here is your Route

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $routeProvider.when("/", {
      template: "<div main-slide-show></div>"
    })
    .when("/page1", {
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: "firstController"
    })
    .when("/page2", {
      templateUrl: "page2.html",
      controller: "secondController"
    })
    .when("/page3", {
      templateUrl: "page3.html",
      controller: "thirdController"
    })
```

})

And create a directive like this

```
.directive("mainSlideShow",function(){
  return{
    template:`<ul class='cb-slideshow'>
            <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>se·ren·i·ty</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>com·po·sure</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>e·qua·nim·i·ty</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>bal·ance</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>qui·e·tude</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3></div></li>
        </ul>`
  }
})
```

Below is your index.html

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="firstController">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/page1">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/page2">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/page3">Page3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when you click It will navigate to the respective page and slideshow will disappear.

Here is the **[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CvbUjyYYWWVPYnbiX9Cg?p=preview)**

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You are welcome. happy to help. Please mark it as answers if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: sorry I forgot about marking it. All done now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ul class='cb-slideshow'>
      <a href="#page1"><li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>London show</h3></div></li></a>
      <a href="#page2"> <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>Paris music show</h3></div></li></a>
    </ul>
```

Try this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CvbUjyYYWWVPYnbiX9Cg?p=preview

Comment: thanks but still not working here is plunkers http://embed.plnkr.co/tMaCF4Fxhte7lWsZHJiJ/

Comment: just remove / from href